# Find repeating sections and output each section to an individual file?

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

Take a text file with lines like:

```
/user$ cat ORIGFILE 
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt 
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232512.txt 
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232508.txt 
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232507.txt 
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232513.txt 
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt
```

If there are duplicate session number (e.g 200289), it should output each repeating section to a file and display like this:

```
 /user$ cat se832p41iEC.200289
 se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt
 se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232507.txt 
 se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232508.txt

 /user$ cat xe832p41iEC.201687
 xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt
 xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232512.txt
 xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232513.txt

 /user$ cat NEWFILE
 pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
 pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt
```

Thank you in advance.

Update: Just figured it out after @Jaypal's hint (thanks man):

```
  First - sort ORIGFILE| uniq -u > NEWFILE
  Second - sort ORIGFILE | uniq -D > AWKFILE
  Last - awk -F_ '{print $0 > $1}' AWKFILE
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only asking Stack Overflow users to write code.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, then we'll help you fix the problems.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to unix, I do know how to output all occurrences using uniq but cannot figure how each section be output to an individual file.

Comment: **Hint:** `awk -F_ '{print $0 > $1}' file`

Comment: @jaypal, I know that but how would it group all separate occurrences to  each indivual file?

Comment: @user3491651 Did you try it?

Comment: @jaypal worked like charm!

Comment: @jaypal sorry but non-repeating session numbers should be in the same file. How would I do that?

Comment: @user3491651 I know, which is why that was a hint and not an answer. Play around with that hint, and update your question with what you have tried. Solving a problem yourself feels far more fulfilling than getting a solution from someone. If you are stuck, we will be here to help.  `:)`.

Comment: SOLVED: Updated question for others having similar problem.

Comment: @user3491651 Now that you showed your attempt, I have added a solution for you. Good luck. If you like it you can accept it (no obligations though) `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have added your attempt, here is a way of doing it with `awk`:

```
$ ls
file

$ cat file
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232512.txt
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232508.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232507.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232513.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt
```

```
$ awk -F_ '{
    a[$1] = (a[$1] ? a[$1] RS $0 : $0)
    b[$1]++
}
END {
    for(x in a) print a[x] > (b[x]>1 ? x : "NEWFILE")
}' file
```

```
$ ls
NEWFILE  file  se832p41iEC.200289  xe832p41iEC.201687
```

```
$ head *
==> NEWFILE <==
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt

==> file <==
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt
pt832p41iEC.213631_EDI832I140401232501.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232512.txt
pt832p41iEC.213632_EDI832I140401232502.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232508.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232507.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232513.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt

==> se832p41iEC.200289 <==
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232506.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232508.txt
se832p41iEC.200289_EDI832I140401232507.txt

==> xe832p41iEC.201687 <==
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232512.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232513.txt
xe832p41iEC.201687_EDI832I140401232511.txt
```